# Unsafe member access .setAttribute on an `any` value. eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access)

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

An error is being thrown from the below code, but the code is still working as expected.

```
import { ..., ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(
    ...,
    private elementRef: ElementRef
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    const keyword: string = 'xyz';
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('key', keyword); // gives error
}
```

Error -

> *Unsafe member access .setAttribute on an 'any' value. eslint([@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-member-access/))*

Whats's the fix?

I was trying to set 'keyword as string', but not working.

`this.elementRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('key', keyword as string);`

Comment: Why would `keyword as string` help at all, considering the error is ***not*** with `keyword` but with `this.elementRef.nativeElement`. And why do you keep posting these self-Q&As? The theme is "here is an error message, I'll not describe *why* am I getting it and I'll try something random that doesn't even match up with the error. Then ask how to fix it and answer with something about what the error message already informs me of". Is there really such a market for people who don't read error message and yet are able to understand the missing context of the code you post?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution -

```
const element: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
element.setAttribute('key', keyword);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem, when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to relevant documentation.

Comment: Definitely need more description and not just a code snippet. Sure it might work, but how, and why?